# MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch Switch: /Y

Tags: msbuild

I'm using team city to make an automatic deploy and MSBuild won't work...
In the build step the the command line parameters look like this:
ProjectName.deploy.cmd /y /M:https://[WebDeployUrl:8172]/MsDeploy.axd /u:username /p:password –allowUntrusted /A:basic

this works fine from my machine, but the build server fails with the following response:
[MSBuild output] MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
[MSBuild output] Switch: /Y

Anyone has an idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, and the asker likely sorted out their issue long ago, but here goes anyways:

MSBuild tasks in TeamCity require a commandline that pertain to MSBuild.exe specifically, IIRC.

That is, TeamCity is executing MSBuild.exe with the parameters you've given it like so:

```
msbuild.exe ProjectName.deploy.cmd /y /M:https://[WebDeployURL]:8172]/MsDeploy.axd /u:username /p:password -allowUntrusted /A:basic
```

Of course, MSbuild has no idea what those switches are, nor would it be able to process 'ProjectName.deploy.cmd' as an MSBuild file.

Comment: What to do with this?

Comment: Instead of using an MSBuild task in Team City, it's likely that you'd just want to run a command-line task instead. It seems to me that the failure is caused by msbuild trying to process the .cmd file here, which makes no sense since msbuild can only process msbuild-style project files.